# How much help should be given to a student?

Tags: discussion, answers, ethics

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565357/write-a-program-in-python-3-5-that-reads-a-file-then-writes-a-different-file-wi/39565448#39565448) where it was very clear the user is a beginner student doing an assignment (I assume to be graded). They were onto the solution, but were stuck.

I posted an answer that was intentionally vague that pointed the student to new leads to help think about the problem. Others posted full answers to the question, including demonstrating a Pythonic solution.

What are the ethical boundaries that should be displayed on stack overflow? Should we be giving solutions to students if they are almost there, or hints so they can learn for themselves?

Comment: If you don't think users should get homework questions answered (and that isn't a controversial stance), then don't answer.  But don't try to "guide" the user, they don't care and it doesn't produce a quality answer most of the time.

Comment: Well you could argue that the ethical-ness is really left up to the OP. If they chose to be dishonest and ask the question here, that is their fault. However the question in context did not mention anything in particular about what his/her teacher said, so it might not be a good idea to assume anything.

Comment: TBH I think for the purposes of creating useful QA whether or not its a homework question is largely irrelevant. OP has to decide if the want to deprive themselfes of learning it on their own.

Comment: No need to assume anything anyway, there is no real question asked here. Its an *"I don't know what I'm doing, halp!"*. That is not something specifically tied to students but to people who need personal guidance to get things done. Alas, Stack Overflow is no digital mentor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're viewing this from the wrong angle.

Instead, treat homework questions like any other question: If the question is well formulated, nicely distinguished and provides sufficient information to answer properly, then answer it if you feel like it.

I don't think we need a special standard for homework questions, since its not really relevant if the question came from a homework assignment or a production problem if it is good, only that its a decent, on topic question matters in this case.